p11-forwarding: NGINX cannot load private key in remote server via unix-socket, but openssl can
I am trying to follow this tutorial https://p11-glue.github.io/p11-glue/p11-kit/manual/remoting.html
I used to struggle with the setup, but thank for the answer here link, I manage to use p11-remote. However, there is a new issue.
After creating a key and a certificate. The private key is stored in remote host. I access it via p11-kit-client. I would like to use them in nginx configuration.
However it got the error: (../nginx/error.log)
2024/11/03 16:58:51 [emerg] 1237#1237: cannot load certificate key "engine:pkcs11:pkcs11:model=SoftHSM%20v2;token=mimi;object=test-key;type=private": ENGINE_load_private_key() failed (SSL: error:40000065:pkcs11 engine::object not found error:13000080:engine routines::failed loading private key) 
2024/11/03 16:59:51 [debug] 1244#1244: bind() 0.0.0.0:10001 #8 
2024/11/03 16:59:51 [debug] 1244#1244: counter: 00007FBE28745080,

It shows that nginx cannot load the key. I double checked with openssl.
openssl req  -engine pkcs11 -keyform engine  -key "pkcs11:model=SoftHSM%20v2;token=mimi;object=test-key;type=private" -new -sha512  -out csr/nginx-test.csr -config req-proxy.cnf
Engine "pkcs11" set.

and
openssl s_client -connect host.docker.internal:443 \
    -engine pkcs11 \
    -keyform engine \
    -key "pkcs11:model=SoftHSM%20v2;token=mimi;object=test-key;type=private" \
    -cert /etc/ssl/certs/bundle.proxytest.crt

to see that OPENSSL can load test-key.
NOTES:

The key generation command is done in local host, then I double check the existion in the remote server, by listing object (p11tool)
ssh connection are activated. Openssl did load the key via active socket pkcs11.
I did try nginx with normal key file, to make sure that nginx is fine with normal key file.
Openssl version 3.0.2. It works with pkcs11 engine.
nginx -t is OK.
Updated: I tried with incorrect URI/ incorrect cert, nginx can detect the error: cannot load key or mismatch cert. I guess It shows that nginx might be able to load the key but cannot start, the error.log still shows that nginx CANNOT load the key.
Nginx configuration file:

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
ssl_engine pkcs11;
http {
    
    upstream nginx_server_backend {
        server nginx-server:10000;
        keepalive 512;
    }
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server {

        listen 10001 ssl;
        ssl_protocols    TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/bundle.proxy.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key "engine:pkcs11:pkcs11:model=SoftHSM%20v2;token=mimi;object=test-key;type=private";
      
    }    
       
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main; 
    access_log /var/log/nginx/ssl_handshake.log ssl_handshake;
 
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

Thank you for your support in advance.

Does the user that nginx is running as have permission to access unix domain socket?

@hardillb yes, I think. Because I run in docker container. every process runs as root. Additionally, I changed the socket’s permissions to allow access for all users. I also use same nginx configuration file to run on remote system, it is Ok (this to check the URI key to be correct),

@hardillb Updated: I tried intentionally with incorrect URI/ incorrect cert, nginx can detect the error: cannot load key or mismatch cert. I guess It shows that nginx might be able to load the key but cannot start, the error.log still shows that nginx CANNOT load the key.
